# What is the concept behind the categorical-encoding used in the CatBoost benchmark problems?

Tags: boosting, categorical-encoding, catboost

I'm working through CatBoost quality benchmark problems ([here](https://github.com/catboost/benchmarks/tree/master/quality_benchmarks)). I'm particularly intrigued by the methodology adopted to convert categorical features to numerical values as described in the comparison_description.pdf ([here](https://github.com/catboost/benchmarks/blob/master/quality_benchmarks/comparison_description.pdf)). What is the reasoning behind this approach? Is this methodology model agnostic? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

[image]